# Can i host my own and private azure platform

Tags: azure

Is it possible to deploy a private servers farm in order to host azure virtual machines ?

Or should i work only with Microsoft servers ?

Thanks

Comment: No, you just can create VM, but you cannot control which physical machine the VMs in.

Comment: My question is like gitlab and github: It is possible to install my own gitlab server but not github. So azur is like github ? We can use it but cannot deploy or own ?

Comment: What do you mean your own? You can do anything in the VM, it just likes the physical machine you use, the difference is that it is virtualization.

Comment: I mean i want to buy 10 servers and i want to run azure VM on this 10 servers

Comment: It's impossible. You cannot buy servers. You can buy a subscription from Azure. Then create the VMs in the subscription.

Comment: If you want to host Azure in your environment, do take a look at Azure Stack - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides the Azure Stack capabilities as part of windows server so that you can build your own Azure private cloud on premises or in a collocation facility.  You can optionally extend this to the public cloud for a hybrid solution.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/